# Check if a number is Carmichael

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, prime-numbers, cryptography, pseudoprimes

I am trying to implement Modified Miller-Rabin Algorithm by Shyam Narayanan (https://math.mit.edu/research/highschool/primes/materials/2014/Narayanan.pdf). The algorithm demands to check if a number is carmichael number. Is there any possible algorithm to check if a number of the order $10^{100}$ is a carmichael number or not in reasonable time on a standard PC?(Other than by efficient factorization)

The Paper also describes that there is a $O(\log(n)^4)$ algo for checking if a number is carmichael or not. Do any such algorithm exists?

Comment: Look up Fermat's Little Theorem and Erdos' method.

Comment: That will be a probabilistic method. Isn't there a way to say for sure if a number is carmichael?

Comment: Yes it has to be probabilistic because there is no feasible way to factorize a big number such as that.

Comment: On page 11-12 of the paper it states "there is no known polynomial time algorithm that determines whether n is a Carmichael number of the form pqr, where p,q,r = 3 mod 4."  They conjecture on page 17 without any comment that it could be done in O(log^4(n)) time, but it isn't clear why they believe this is true.  Regardless, adding a strong Lucas test to a base 2 Miller-Rabin test has been shown to be very effective and seemingly of more practical use than this (but it's nice to see).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check, whether the given number $n$ is prime. (This can be done efficiently and $100$% correct very fast for numbers with about $100$ digits).

If the number is prime, it is not a carmichael number.

Go through the numbers $a$ coprime to $n$ and check whether $a^{n-1}\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ n\ )$ holds.

If you find such an $a$, for which this is not the case, the number is not carmichael.

It will not take too long to find a base $a$, such that $n$ is pseudoprime to base $a$, but not strong pseudoprime (or you find a base $a$, such that $n$ is not even pseudoprime to base $a$, in which case you are done).

In this case, you can efficiently find a non-trivial factor because you get a non-trivial congruence $s^2\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ n\ )$.

It is not known, whether you find a base $a$ "quickly", but in practise you will probably always succeed.

Comment: what is s here? Is it this s : n-1 = d.2^s. I dont properly understand how will I be able to find a factor if I find a base for which n is pseudoprime but not strong pseudoprime.

Comment: No, not this $s$. If $n-1=2^sd$ with $d$ odd, we must have a $t<s$ with $a^{2^td}\ne \pm 1$ , but $a^{2^{t+1}d}=1$ modulo $n$. This gives a non-trivial congruence $u^2=1$ modulo $n$, where $u:=2^{2^td}$

Comment: You should repeat this process with different bases $a$ until all factors of $n$ are found.

Comment: I appreciate you help, but I am new to number theory and I still dont understand how will I get factors, even if I find u?

Comment: $gcd(u-1,n)$ and $gcd(u+1,n)$ are non-trivial factors.

Comment: Thanks a lot I understood the algorithm. In your comment above you wrote u:= 2^(d.2^t), shouldn't the base be "a" instead of 2?

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry!

Comment: Yes, if the number is not pseudoprime to base $a$, you get no non-trivial factor this way. Otherwise, integer factorization would be trivial, which is probably not the case.

Comment: I have implemented the algo and it is working pretty fine but I observed that for number 825265 , I cannot find the "a".

Comment: The wikipedia page of carmichael number says this is a carmichael number. There are some more big carmichael numbers on the page that also fail the test.

Comment: I ran the loop of "a" from 2 to 825625, but no base a could be found.

Comment: How did you implement your program ?

Comment: for base 2, we do not get any t >=0 and t<s such that a^(d.2^(t+1)) = 1 mod n. Here are the values at all iterations: 524798, 262140, -446606, 217300, -592306. It never becomes 1. So, no "t" exists.

Comment: In my implementation, after finding base "a" such that n is a pseudoprime, I check if n is not strong pseudoprime, I check it by first finding "d", then I loop and check if a^(d.2^(t+1)) = 1 mod n and make this value square in every iteration uptill I reach n-1.

Comment: I corrected my implementation. its running now.. Thanks a lot for all the help.

Comment: actually integer overflow was happening.

Comment: The aim of the question is to implement a prime-testing algorithm using a method that first requires to rule out that the integer tested is a Charmichael number. Therefore _"First check, whether the given number $n$ is prime"_ reaches that aim without requiring implementation of the rest of the answer.

Comment: If n is a large Carmichael number, won't this be completely impractical as it takes n-2 steps?

Comment: @DanaJ In the case the number is Carmichael, but not prime, we probably (there is no proof for that) find a "small" base $a$ coprime to $n$ (otherwise we already found a non-trivial factor), such that $n$ is NOT STRONG-probable prime to base $a$. A carmichael number is pseudoprime to every base $a$ coprime to $n$, but not necessarily strong-pseudoprime. In practice, the algorithm will be relatively efficient. $n-2$ steps will not be needed.

Comment: @Peter, thanks.  It still seems like an algorithm inappropriate for the paper's intent, but I don't think there are any good ones.  I'm also still not following how we conclude "this number is Carmichael" from this algorithm.  n=341,a=2 satisfies the conditions a^(n-1)=1 mod n, is pseudoprime, and not strong pseudoprime.  But 341 isn't a Carmichael number.  Maybe you're just stopping when we've determined the number isn't prime?

Comment: @DanaJ No, the OP wants to check whether a number is Carmichael. The idea is : First we check whether the number is prime. If it isn't, we either find non-trivial factors until we can check whether $n$ is Carmichael via its prime factors OR we find a base $a$ coprime to $n$ , such that $n$ is not pseudoprime to base $a$. I do NOT conlude that the number is Carmichael, if I find a non-trivial factor. I only stop when $n$ is not pseudoprime to base $a$, otherwise I continue searching non-trivial factors.

Comment: Maybe, I did not fomulate this precisely enough...

Answer (score 4):

There are different ways to find out. For such a big number we need a method without having to factorize it.

One way to start, is to prove that N is composite. Therefore we choose a strong primality-test like the one of Miller–Rabin,Solovay–Strassen or the newer APRCL-test.
If this test returns false, the compositeness of N is proven.

Next choose a test based on Fermat's little theorem:

$a^{p}\equiv a \ (mod\ p)$
for all integer $a$ with $0<a<p$ and $p \in primes$.

Proceed as follows:

pick a random $a$ with $1<a<N-1$ .

case 1:
$a^{N-1}\equiv 1 \ (mod\ N)$ then pick another $a$ and repeat the test.

case 2:
$a^{N-1}\not\equiv 1 \ (mod\ N)$ and $gcd(a,N)= 1$ then $N$ is composite but not a Carmichael number. We are finished.

case 3:
$a^{N-1}\not\equiv 1 \ (mod\ N)$ and $gcd(a,N)\neq 1$ then $N$ is composite and $gcd(a,N)$ is a non-trivial Divisor of $N$. Pick another $a$ and repeat the test.

for case 1 and 3 repeat the test $k$-times. When finished $N$ is a Carmichael number with probability $1-2^{-k}$.

Here is my implementation for Pari-gp:

```
iscarmichael(n)={ \\input: positive integer n > 1
my(a=0,k=100); \\returns 1, if n is a Carmichael number with probability 1-2^-k
if(n%2==0||ispseudoprime(n)==1,return(0));
for(t=1,k,a=random(n-3)+2;if(lift(Mod(a,n)^(n-1))<>1&&gcd(a,n)==1,return(0)));
return(1)
};
```

The function iscarmichael(n) returns 1, if n is a Carmichael number with probability $1-2^{-k}$, 
otherwise it returns 0. Parameter k is set to 100. You can increase k for higher probability or decrease for lower probability.

Comment: This shares the same property of including a primality test as an early step, making it recursive for the paper's purpose of a pretest for Miller-Rabin.  Regardless, I'd recommend first doing a quick divisibility check with 4,9,25,49,121,169 which immediately cuts out many non-square free numbers.  Other than that, leaving out the primality test this is a great iscarmichael pre-test or probable iscarmichael function.