# Carmichael Numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Carmichael numbers are false positives to the Fermat Primality Test, which makes it difficult to distinguish between Carmichael numbers and prime numbers. Is there any significance in distinguishing between Carmichael numbers and other composite numbers, as seen here: [Check if a number is Carmichael](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1726016/check-if-a-number-is-carmichael)?

Comment: See whether this helps you: http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2002-71-238/S0025-5718-01-01355-2/S0025-5718-01-01355-2.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Though I understand that Erdos found a construction for Carmichael numbers, I still do not know if there is any significance to testing if a given composite number is Carmichael.

Comment: @S.Little Yes there is. In CS we use Primality testing algorithms and there we use probabilistic algorithms sometimes. So Using Fermat's Little Theorem and Carmichael number testing we get an extremely good approximation whether the number is prime or not. Doing the test repeatedly we can know for sure that the number is prime or composite.

Comment: @UserNotFound Does your comment refer to Carmichael numbers or to arbitary composite numbers ? If it is the latter, which test do you mean ?

Comment: @Peter I was referring to Miller Rabin Algorithm in particular. I am not sure what I had in mind 1 year earlier but this is what I wanted to say : If we can detect whether an arbitrary (composite) number is Carmichael number, we can use that test. If number is Carmichael its composite. If not we can then use Fermat's test (the first half of Miller Rabin test) and be done. Did I make sense?

Comment: Even repeated strong-fermat-pseudoprime-tests never guarantee that a number is prime. Your formulation : "for sure that the number is prime or composite" hence confused me.