# Large Carmichael number

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, carmichael-numbers

I need to find or generate a very large Carmichael number (500 digits or longer). I've tried to find a database or just an example of such a number but failed. Is there any examples of really big Carmichael numbers or an implementation of an algorithm I'd be able to run locally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the best approach is to search a positive integer $k$, such that $6k+1$ , $12k+1$ , $18k+1$ are all prime. Then $$N=(6k+1)(12k+1)(18k+1)$$ is a Carmichael-number. If you find $k>10^{170}$ with the desired property , you are done.

Comment: For example , $$k=10^{170}+8786356$$ does the job

Comment: I can confirm that it is a (probable) Carmichael number using a Pascal implementation of the algorithm from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1729144/61216

Comment: I tested the factors with the APR-test. They are in fact all prime.

Comment: https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00076980/document could be of interest to you.